# Python, counting the number of even digits

Tags: python

for  homework in an introductory python class, one of the questions is to count the number of even numbers in n. here's my code so far:

```
def num_even_digits(n):
    i=0
    count = 0
    while i < n:
        i+=1
        if n%2==0:
            count += 1
    return count

print(num_even_digits(123456))
```

Answer (score 1):

Pythonic answer:

```
def num_even_digits(x):
    return len([ y for y in str(x) if int(y) % 2 == 0])

print(num_even_digits(123456))
```

Disclaimer: I recognized that, for an *introductory* Python class, my answer may not be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing the whole number every time. you need to convert it to a string and then loop over every number in that string of numbers, cast it back to an integer and see if its remainder is 0

```
def num_even_digits(numbers):
    count = 0
    numbers = str(numbers)
    for number in numbers:
        try:
            number = int(number)
        except ValueError:
            continue

        if number % 2 == 0:
            count += 1
    return count

print(num_even_digits(123456))
```

if you want to actually loop through every possible number in the range of 0 to your large number you can do this.

```
def num_even_digits(numbers):
    count = 0
    for number in range(0, numbers):
        if number % 2 == 0:
            count += 1
    return count

print(num_even_digits(10))
```

problems with your current function:

```
def num_even_digits(n): # n is not descriptive, try to make your variable names understandable
    i=0
    count = 0
    while i < n: # looping over every number from 0 to one hundred twenty three thousand four hundred and fifty six.
        i+=1
        if n%2==0: # n hasn't changed so this is always going to be true
            count += 1
    return count

print(num_even_digits(123456))
```